# How to validate if specific string entered by user is in text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch script wherein when a user inputs a word, the script will search for that string entered by the user in a specific file.

I have been able to find if it exists in the file but the problem is I cannot seem to make it specific only to what the user has entered.

For my file I use a .dat extension, below is a sample content of my file.

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
```

In my scenario when I the user inputs `user1` the script tells me that it is valid or in the list, but when the user inputs `user`or `1,2,3,4,5` it still tells me that it is valid. Is there any way to make it only specific to what the user enters?

Now I'm having a hard time on how I should do this. Below is my sample code.

```
@echo off

set /p word=


findstr /c:%word% test.dat > Nul
if ErrorLevel 1 (
echo.Not Valid

    ) else (
    echo.Valid
    )

pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
findstr /X /c:"%word%" test.dat > Nul
```

The `/x` switch insists on an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use the [start and end of word markers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx):

```
\<xyz   Word position: beginning of word
xyz\>   Word position: end of word
```

Basically what this means is that `\<` says start from the beginning of a word; this beginning is defined as various factors like being at the start of a line, having a space or other punctuation, etc, and similarly `\>` says match the end, such as the next character being the end of file or end of line, space or punctuation, etc. So, if you have a line like:

```
user1 user2,user3user4
```

`\<user1\>` and `\<user2\>` would match as there are word start and end points surrounding them, but `\<user3\>` fails because there is a `u` after `user3`, which is not an end of word character, and `\<user4\>` fails because there is a `3` before `user4`, which is not a start of word character.

This works for me:

```
findstr /r /c:"\<%word%\>" test.dat > Nul
```

Note that the `/r` flag is needed to turn on regular expressions. Also note there doesn't seem to be a flag to turn off output so you don't need to redirect to `Nul`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm still confused on the word positioning that you have posted though.

Comment: @KarlGuevarra I've added more description. Note that Magoo's answer matches the complete line, so if, say `%word%` equalled `Ken`, my code would match a line `Ken Y-N`, but his wouldn't, which is perhaps preferred behaviour.